# How to disable port access from other AWS regions inside AWS security group

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-security-group

I would like to create simple rule in AWS security group which would, by default, enable access to specific port ONLY to the instances running in specific AWS region (for example: us-east-1).
I know that security groups are tied to specific AWS region and with that assumption, I thought there is some straightforward way to create rule in security group for specific port which would disable access for requests coming from instances in other AWS regions.

While google-ing around, I've found a list of ip ranges for specific regions on AWS: https://ip-ranges.amazonaws.com/ip-ranges.json but list is not small so adding list of all ip ranges for specific region would be my last resort.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As written, you don't provide enough information. Is this traffic coming from a [VPC peer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/peering/what-is-vpc-peering.html)? Or are you looking to restrict connections that cross the Internet?

Comment: Very simply, if possible, I'm looking for a solution to restrict access from instances deployed on any other region except "us-east-1". That being said, traffic is not coming from any particular VPC peer.

Comment: To rephrase: you want to block Internet traffic that originates in a different AWS region, but you don't want to block traffic from any other origin (such as Google Cloud Platform). That doesn't make any sense. What is the _real_ problem that you're trying to solve?

Comment: To make it simple: I want to block all traffic on particular port that originates from anywhere except instances running in specific AWS region (for example: us-east-1)

Comment: So you're OK if somebody else connects to your server because they happen to be in the same region? I'm guessing not. So I'll ask again, and for the last time, what is the _real_ problem that you're trying to solve? And why can't you solve it using either elastic IPs (which can be individually whitelisted in your security groups) or using ingress rules based on other security groups?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The list that you are referencing `ip-ranges.json` only lists AWS resources and not other IP addresses that may exist in other regions.

Security groups are not tied to an AWS region. Security Groups are a software defined network (SDN) firewall attached to a network interface. Security Groups have no inherit knowledge of AWS Regions.

Short of using geolocation, there is no reliable method to know where traffic originates when it arrives at the AZ of your instance. An AWS region does not use only a specified IP address range. An AWS region can change the addressing ranges (adding, deleting, etc.) at any time. AWS supports `Bring Your Own IP` which further makes this impossible.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. By saying "security group is tied to an AWS region", I thought that security group created in region "us-east-1" is not visible as such in other regions (from the point of AWS management console). Of course, it makes sense what you are saying that it is firewall attached to network interface.

Comment: Just about everything in AWS is region specific. The point that I am trying to clarify is that security groups are tied to network interfaces. Here is an example of using security groups across regions: "If you have a VPC peering connection, you can reference security groups from the peer VPC as the source or destination in your security group rules." https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_SecurityGroups.html